# How can I remove the inner scroll from a GridView?

Tags: android, ios, gridview, flutter, dart

I am trying to have a ListView with one single scroll. I want to be able to scroll down and see every widget. Currently, I have multiple widgets before a GridView. The problem with this is that the GridView has its own scroll. A good example of what I want is similar to the Instagram profile page. When you scroll down in the Instagram profile page, every element scrolls down. There are no nested scrolls.

This is my current code:

```dart
body: ListView(
children: <Widget>[
  ...
  ...
Container(
  child: GridView.count(
           crossAxisCount: 3,
           shrinkWrap: true,
           children: List.generate(100, (index) {
                  return Container(
                           alignment: Alignment.center,
                           margin: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                           child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                           placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                          image:'https://picsum.photos/${300}/${300}/',
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              )
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's Nested Scrolled Widgets, the `CustomScrollView` which takes Slivers to achieve what you're looking for. SliverGrid and SliverList are the ones you need to achieve your goal:

```
Widget sliverScroll() {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverGrid(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            return Container();
          }, childCount: 9),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            return Container();
          }, childCount: 6),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

You can customize as you wish, changing the order or it, item count, etc

Comment: Glad it work! Make sure to mark my answer as correct to help more people with it.